# How do I get boost-bjam to properly id my libraries when they build?

Tags: boost-python, bjam

On Debian/squeeze in /usr/lib I have:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py25.so         /usr/lib/libboost_python-py26.so
```

I'm trying to build

```
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so
```

to go with a pythonbrewed version of python 2.7 by specifying `--buildID=py27`.  But bjam keeps generating only

```
libboost_python.so.1.42.0
```

and then a link to

```
libboost_python.so
```

How do I get bjam and the Jamroot of boost to give me an appropriately named .so?  I'm guessing the package maintainers managed to do it......

The command lines I have tried are:

```
bjam --layout=tagged --buildID=py27 --with-python
bjam --buildID=py27 --with-python
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with the latest Boost version you should be able to do:

```
b2 --python-buildid=py27 --with-python
```

But if you must use 1.42 the syntax would be:

```
bjam --buildid=py27 --with-python
```

In other words.. The options are in lower case and are case *sensitive*.